# Extra space on top and bottom of android Chip material component

Tags: android, material-design, android-view, material-components-android, android-chips

I'm using **Chip** view in my layout 
Since upgraded material design component from *1.0.0* to *1.1.0*, there is an extra space at the **top** and **bottom** of view 
I couldn't find any document about how to remove these spaces

**In material 1.0.0**

[image]

**In material 1.1.0**

[image]

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Action"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:text="Groceries"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Can you add your code as **TEXT** instead of image?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It is related to the [`chipMinTouchTargetSize`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.1.0/lib/java/com/google/android/material/chip/res/values/styles.xml#L54) attribute.
You can find in the `Chip` [source code](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.1.0/lib/java/com/google/android/material/chip/Chip.java#L240):

```
if (shouldEnsureMinTouchTargetSize()) {
  setMinHeight(minTouchTargetSize);
}
```

You can change the `chipMinTouchTargetSize` in the layout or in the style:

```
    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        app:chipMinTouchTargetSize="32dp"
        ../>
```

or you can set `app:ensureMinTouchTargetSize="false"`.

[image]

Pay attention to change this value since it changes the minimum touch target size.